# Get sum on current subform

Tags: ms-access, cumulative-sum

I have a "Mainform" in Microsoft Access that automatically computes the summation of my "Subform". Now my trouble is this, in my "Subform" there is a Yes/No check box that corresponds on Amount_Lent, Date and Name. I want to get the total summation of the Amount_Lent in my current "Subform" when the value of my check box is "Yes".

Would it be possible to use the DSUM function using VBA?

Comment: I would say... try it and see what happens

Comment: you don't need  VBA for this. just use the =Dsum(amount_lent,table_name, [yes/noFieldName] <> false)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of with a custom function:

```
Public Function AmountLentSum() As Currency

    Dim rs        As DAO.Recordset
    Dim AmountSum As Currency

    Set rs = Me!NameOfSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone
    While Not rs.EOF
        If rs!YourCheckBox.Value = True Then
            AmountSum = AmountSum + Nz(rs!Amount_Lent.Value, 0)
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    AmountLentSum = AmountSum

End If
```

Then use as ControlSource: =AmountLenSum()